# Does extra smoothness between two DIFFERENT substances cause the friction to increase?

Tags: friction

I know it happens when the elements on both sides are identical, the more you remove asperities, the more they become like a single substance. But does this happen to the same extent if I take two different substances and start removing asperities? Or maybe close to that...
My textbook doesn't explain much about this, it says "By making the surfaces extra smooth, frictional force increases as actual area of contact increases and two bodies in contact act like a single body." Doesn't say anything about the substances taken.

Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be an adhesive force between any two materials. That force tends to be strongest when the materials are the same, but the Van der Waals force always exists, even though in some cases it may be very weak. This means the greater the actual area of contact the greater the adhesive force and the greater the friction.

I suppose I should not rule out the possibility that there might exist two materials that fundamentally repel each other, though I don't know of any such system.